# java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not deserialize object. Expected a List, but got a class java.lang.String (found in field 'image')

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

The above error is showing when I want to open the app on my mobile phone. But it works normally on emulator.

The model class is:

```
data class Product(
    var charge: List<String>? = emptyList(),
    var description: String? = "",
    var id: String? = "",
    var image: List<String>? = emptyList(),
    var name: String? = "",
    var priceA: List<String>? = emptyList(),
    var priceD: List<String>? = emptyList(),
    var quantity: List<String>? = emptyList(),
    var size: List<String>? = emptyList(),
    var tag: List<String>? = emptyList()
) : Parcelable
```

Data retrieving code from Firestore DataBase :

```
db.addSnapshotListener { snapshot, e->
                if(e!=null){
                    return@addSnapshotListener
                }
                productList = snapshot!!.toObjects(Product::class.java)
                adapter = Adapter(productList, this@HomeActivity, ProductInterface::class.java)
                fireStoreList.adapter = adapter
                fireStoreList.setHasFixedSize(true)
                fireStoreList.layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(this@HomeActivity, 2)
                hideProgress()
            }
```

structure of data in Firestore Database:

[image]

Logcat :

> 2021-04-08 22:50:21.404 7509-7509/com.example.modshabuisness
> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> Process: com.example.modshabuisness, PID: 7509
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not deserialize object. Expected a List, but got a class java.lang.String (found in field 'image')
> at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.CustomClassMapper.deserializeError(CustomClassMapper.java:563)
> at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.CustomClassMapper.deserializeToParameterizedType(CustomClassMapper.java:276)
> at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.CustomClassMapper.deserializeToType(CustomClassMapper.java:187)
> at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.CustomClassMapper.access$300(CustomClassMapper.java:54)
> at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper.deserialize(CustomClassMapper.java:770)
> at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper.deserialize(CustomClassMapper.java:741)
> at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.CustomClassMapper.convertBean(CustomClassMapper.java:542)
> at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.CustomClassMapper.deserializeToClass(CustomClassMapper.java:253)
> at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.CustomClassMapper.convertToCustomClass(CustomClassMapper.java:100)
> at com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot.toObject(DocumentSnapshot.java:183)
> at com.google.firebase.firestore.QueryDocumentSnapshot.toObject(QueryDocumentSnapshot.java:116)
> at com.google.firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot.toObjects(QuerySnapshot.java:184)
> at com.google.firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot.toObjects(QuerySnapshot.java:166)
> at com.example.modshabuisness.activity.HomeActivity$onCreate$3.onEvent(HomeActivity.kt:93)
> at com.example.modshabuisness.activity.HomeActivity$onCreate$3.onEvent(HomeActivity.kt:37)
> at com.google.firebase.firestore.Query.lambda$addSnapshotListenerInternal$2(Query.java:1133)
> at com.google.firebase.firestore.Query$$Lambda$3.onEvent(Unknown
> Source:6)
> at com.google.firebase.firestore.core.AsyncEventListener.lambda$onEvent$0(AsyncEventListener.java:42)
> at com.google.firebase.firestore.core.AsyncEventListener$$Lambda$1.run(Unknown
> Source:6)
> at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:255)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8214)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:632)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1049)

Comment: Are you sure it's that document causing the problem? Your `image` field doesn't look incorrect.

Comment: yes link appears in logcat indicates the document. But it works well on emulator. Is it the problem of device?

Comment: I very much doubt it, but that is very strange... Can you include the code you use to retrieve the data?

Comment: Yes it is strange. Now i run this app on Samsung device, it works perfectly but on Oppo it doesn't.

Comment: Share your response plaese

Answer (score 1):

It seems that when you have more than one Image it response as a List of Images but somehow when you have only one Image it response it as a String thats why you have deserialization error. Unfortunately, the deserializer cannot put a String to a List of Strings

Comment: Now i insert one more image but still the same problem. The same code is running well on other devices but on OPPO F11 PRO it shows the error

Comment: I think it is a problem of android 11.